# Does Windows Azure offer High performance computing functionalities with CUDA or openCL?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services

I am learning CUDA and would like to implement CUDA programs. I found that amazon offers a cloud based solution for developers who are interested in writing CUDA programs
http://aws.amazon.com/gpu/.
I was not able to find anything similar on windows azure. I would like to know if Azure has any such High performance computing functionalities ?

Answer (score 2):

Azure doesn't have those kinds of facilities. The closest you'll get is an extra large compute instance, or HDInsights, which is their Azure distribution.

Microsoft has a similar tool chain for C++ called C++ AMP (Accelerated Massive Parallelism) so I'd expect that'll be supported first.

Answer (score 0):

The question is already old, so things have changed! :)

Azure will offer soon a N class server which is equiped with Nvidia Tesla K80 card(s) to be used with CUDA and OpenCL.

[Here is some more information](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/azurecon-2015-applications-that-scale-using-gpu-compute/)